# ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression error

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I dont understand the error that I got!

My question is that I have to display the name of the employees and the number of conferences they worked on. And if the employee did not work directly on any conference, have to display 0 for that employee. The tables associated with this query are:

Employee_C table:

```
 EID  NAME   SALARY          MID
---    -------------------- -----
e01   Wilson    53000
e02   Smith      48000       e01
e03   Jones      38000       e01
e04   Loftus     41000
e05   Fox        54000       e04
e06   Smith      45000       e04
e07   Green     48000
e08   Fox         49000      e04
e09   Wolf       41000       e04
e10   Wang        32000      e01
e11   Phillips   33000       e07
e12   Liu         27000      e07
```

Deals_C table:

```
EID CONFID
---    ------
e02   c00001
e03   c00001
e05   c00001
e06   c00001
e03   c00002
e08   c00002
e09   c00002
e10   c00002
e03   c00003
e05   c00003
e06   c00004
e08   c00005
e09   c00005
e10   c00005
e06   c00005
e11   c00006
e12   c00006
e05   c00007
e06   c00007
e08   c00007
e09   c00008
e10   c00008
e11   c00008
e02   c00009
e12   c00009
e10   c00010
e02   c00011
e03   c00011
e05   c00011
e12   c00012
e06   c00012
```

The sql statement that I have is

```
  select E.Name, D.ConfID as "Number of Conferences" 
     from Employee_C E  left outer join Deals_C D on E.eid = D.eid group by E.eid;
```

The error:

select E.Name, D.ConfID as "Number of Conferences" 
        *
Error on Line 1:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Please help!
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an aggregate function and you are using a `GROUP BY` on a column not in the `SELECT` list. You need to `GROUP BY E.Name` since that column is in the select:

```
select E.Name, count(D.ConfID) as "Number of Conferences" 
from Employee_C E  
left outer join Deals_C D 
  on E.eid = D.eid 
group by E.Name;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1a5ae/8)